# integrate the flux of F(z,y,0> across S, if S is a triangular region with vertices (1,0,0), (0,-2,0) and (0,0,10),upward orientation?

Tags: calculus, surface-integrals

When I took the note from class

my instructor begins with

Ax+By+Cz =1, then solve for A when B,C are 0, and solve for B and C by doing the same.

My question is, where is Ax+By+Cz =1 coming from?

Also, I need some help visualize the boundaries for the integral
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your instructor writes the equation $Ax + By + C z = D$ because this is the general equation for a plane. You can normalize $D$ by dividing through if we know the plane doesn't contain the origin, this is where the $1$ comes from.

$$\frac{A}{D} x + \frac{B}{D} y + \frac{C}{D} z = 1$$

By renaming the constants, we arrive back to the general expression, so we can proceed without loss of generality with the equation your professor wrote.

$$A' x + B' y + C' z = 1$$

where $A' = A/D, B' = B/D$ and $C' = C/D$. In reference to how your professor obtains the bounds, he/she solves for $z$ in terms of $x,y$ i.e $z = f(x,y)$. Therefore $f: D \to \textbf{Plane}$ where $D$ will be the domain you are integrating over. To determine that, you observe that it is just the intersection of your plane with the $x,y$-plane, which in this case is $z = 0$. From here you'll get a triangular region in the plane and now you determine the limits from that picture.

Comment: No problem my friend. And once you write the equation for the plane, it'll be clear how to get the other bounds, but I'll explain in an edit above.